# Illustrator script for Flip Horizontal

Tags: javascript, transform, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Salvete!  I have searched high and low, but can't figure out how to use Extendscript (jsx) to flip a single, selected object horizontally.

Can anyone help?  Surely this isn't a difficult one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
mySelection = activeDocument.selection;
if (mySelection.length>0){
    var doc = app.activeDocument;                   //current document
    var s    = doc.selection;                              //current slection
    var sl   = s.length;                                     //number of selected objects
    var m  = app.getScaleMatrix(-100,100);       //H flip matrix - feel free to change to (100,-100) for vertical flip, etc.
    for(var i = 0 ; i < sl; i++) s[i].transform(m); //for each selected element apply the flip matrix
    app.redraw();
}else{
    alert("Nothing selected!")
}
```

Alternatively you can use a **Transform Effect** (*via Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform...*) on your selection with **Reflect X** selected, which will flip each object in the selection individually:

[image: Illustrator H Mirror Transform Effect]

Comment: Say, now that snippet is right nice.  That would have taken me a day or two to figure out just that thing, as I don't do that much extendscript.  Now, after I run the command, it doesn't actually flip until I click somewhere on the screen.  Is there something to add that will update the screen?  I am calling the function via a com runscript command.

Comment: If flips each element in the selection. If you want, you can save the script in the Illustrator Presets/{language}/Scripts folder which will make it available via File > Scripts and you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it. I don't know what a com runscript command is.

Comment: No, I got it:  Add this after the last "for" statement:  `app.redraw();`  I added a bit of a wrapper to the whole thing; mind if I edit your post with the final working script?

Comment: That's real nice - it flips all the selected objects.  That's great!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still didn't figure out how to flip a selected object, but here is a page with a script to flip every object on the page.  This is close; it doesn't deserve a cigar, however.

http://js4ai.blogspot.de/2010/11/flip-on-x-axis.html

Okay, Mr. Profenza has the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I do this with applescript, and "fastscripts" I have it bound to command + shift + H (& V)

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    if (count page items in document 1) > 0 then
        set selectedItems to selection
        set scaleMatrix to get scale matrix horizontal scale -100.0 vertical scale 100.0
        transform every item in selectedItems using scaleMatrix
    end if
end tell
```